# I have a long equation with Range() and math operations. I get Compile error - Sub Function Not Defined

Tags: excel, vba

I get a

> Compile Error - sub function not defined

in my equation which is only mathematical operations. Only 1 of the `Range()` operators is flagged.  `Range ("O8")` at the end of the equation. For the love of me I cannot see why this would happen.

```vb
If Range("O8") = 0 Then
    Range("B10:K10)").Value = Null
Else
    Range("B10") = Range("B8") / Range("O8")
    Range("C10") = Range("C8") / Range("O8")
    Range("D10") = Range("D8") / Range("O8")
    Range("E10") = Range("E8") / Range("O8")
    Range("F10") = Range("F8") / Range("O8")
    Range("G10") = Range("G8") / Range("O8")
    Range("H10") = Range("H8") / Range("O8")
    Range("I10") = Range("I8") / Range("O8")
    Range("J10") = Range("J8") / Range("O8")
    Range("K10") = Range("K8") / Range("O8")
 End If

'MsgBox "Range (O8)=" & Range("O8")

Range("O15").Value = Round(IfError(141.5 / ((((141.5 / (Range("B15") +   131.5)) * Range("B8")) _
    + ((141.5 / (Range("C15") + 131.5)) * Range("C8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("D15") + 131.5)) * _
    Range("D8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("E15") + 131.5)) * Range("E8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("F15") + 131.5)) * _
    Range("F8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("G15") + 131.5)) * Range("G8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("H15") + 131.5)) * _
    Range("H8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("I15") + 131.5)) * Range("I8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("J15") + 131.5)) * _
    Range("J8")) + ((141.5 / (Range("K15") + 131.5)) * Range("K8"))) / _
    Range("O8")) - 131.5, 0), 4)
```

Comment: Are you trying to put a **formula** in a cell, or the **result** of a formula in a cell ??

Answer (score 0):

Excel is telling you that `IfError()` is a function for a worksheet cell and not part pf the VBA function list.

1. If you want to put a **formula** in the cell, then you must create a string that "looks like"" the formula you would have typed and insert it like:  `Range("O15").Formula="=SUM(A1+B1)"`
2. Only if you want to put a **value** in the cell should you try to do the calculation in VBA

Comment: I do not want to put a formula in the cell "O8", I want to put the results of the calculation.  But I think I need to change the way iferror is used in VBA to something like Application.Function.iferror(Range(1)/Range(2), "something")

Comment: This issue has been resolved by using Application.Workseet.Function.Iferror instead of just Iferror in the equation.

Comment: @jceast7  Are there any other open issues??

Answer (score 0):

In your macro, replace `IfError` by `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError` (this is a general way to use worksheet functions within VBA code).
Normally, when you start typing `Application.WorksheetFunction.`, the code completion should show you `IfError` as one of the possibilities.